# Expresso Store: Registering Members - Specify member group in template

Tags: expresso-store

I am setting a site up where customers purchase memberships.

I was going to setup a product to handle this and then do a check in the checkout tag to see if the product had been bought and if it had specify a member id to add that user, during checkout, to their new member group.

Unless there is a better way overall, I am hoping there may be a way within the Registering Members templating to specify a member id

Any help, much appreciated.
Thanks.

See: https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#registering_members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to specify which member group a member goes into when registering a member via checkout. Store will place the member in the default member group that you have set it in the Members > Preferences > Default Member Group Assigned to New Members.

Since EE only allow s members to be assigned to a single member group you would have issues if you offered multiple products at the same time that could assign members to different groups. Store does not currently have a mechanism to handle this kind of functionality.

If you need to assign member IDs or groups other then default you would need to create an extension to handle the logic required and override the default behavior